# Can I hook return value of "Ctrl+Alt+Del"?

Tags: c++, c, mfc

On windows, windows security screen(including log off, sutdown, taskmgr and so on) is appeared when we push <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>.

But I want to make show up my application(MFC) when we hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>.

So I need the return value of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>.

How to get the return value from <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> or what is return value from it?

Comment: The return value is 42. You get it from the function deep_thought().

Comment: What do you mean by "return value"? You appear to want to show your application when those keys are pressed, but that's not the same thing as a "return value". Are you trying to determine what action the user took after pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del (e.g., locking the workstation)?

Comment: @Cody: I think he means the key-code. Like in BASIC, the key code returned for the Esc key is 27, the key-code for space is 32, and the 'enter/return' key is 13. There are key-codes for keys which are pressed together too...which is what danny want's to know.

Answer (score 9):

Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve? You probably will not (and most certainly should not) be able to re-hook the Secure Attention Sequence to perform application-specific actions. What you can do, however, is customize or replace the login component (GINA) that is responsible for handling the SAS -- this might be useful, for example, in kiosk systems where you want to restrict users from logging out.

MSDN Magazine had an article on that a while back, which you might find interesting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx

Comment: I think GINA has been replaced by credential providers or something similar in recent versions of Windows.

Comment: @David Ah, shame. Always liked the acronym. Yep, GINA's gone since Vista. :/

Comment: +1 for reading the asker's mind and providing an alternate solution.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> combination is handled by [`Winlogon`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Alt-Delete#Windows_NT_.28and_later_versions.29) process. You cannot interfere with it due to security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You should write your own [msgina.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543(v=VS.85).aspx); it is not an easy task, but doing it you'll be able to control much more than just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is a system hot key registered by the process winlogon in early versions of Windows (that is, 2000/XP pre SP1). You cannot override the registration or hook the WM_HOTKEY message (at least not in a safe way). It is understandable that the OS prefers operating system (specifically the Winlogon process) rather than a third party program to get the user's password, but want to be flexible in case the user want to authenticate via fingerprint, smart card, etc [read more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Alt-Delete#Windows_NT_.28and_later_versions.29) .

On Windows 2000/XP the official way to customize the login experience is to write your own Gina (detailed in the article linked in ig2r's reply) but Gina can conflict with each other (e.g. A Think Pad laptop with fingerprint login has problem with McAfee Safeboot, pcAnywhere, etc). Gina is gone in Vista.

On Windows Vista or later the way you can customize the logon experience is [credential provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx). It's extensibility is limited, but you still get an HWND via ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents::OnCreatingWindow in case you want to display a dialog in response of credential provider events. The documented way to use the HWND as the owner of your dialog (be win32 or MFC or whatever).

Of cause there is always the [keyboard driver filter approach,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543456(VS.85).aspx) provided you know driver development and user mode-kernel mode communication for each Windows version. [You can even block the whole keyboard if you want.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651708)