# How to Measure Mouse Speed without the Mouse actually Moving in Java?

Tags: java, mouse

In Java, how can I measure the speed of the mouse movement but disable the actual cursor movement. For example, when someone swipes their mouse across a table, I want to measure how fast he/she swiped the mouse without the cursor actually moving.

I've tried doing this by resetting the mouse position to a specific coordinate (robot class) but the mouse is able to escape when I swipe really fast.

If this is not possible in Java, a C# or C++ solution would be okay.

Thanks

Comment: You could always try to hide the mouse. Reset it's position on regular intervals to the center of the screen, and in the meanwhile calculate the pixel_distance / time_difference (based on time in mileseconds for example). Should be possible in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really want to block mouse movement events you'd need to do it much lower - in c/c++ at the input filter layer. here's a question to point you in the right direction: [Blocking mouse input from a service in Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651708/blocking-mouse-input-from-a-service-in-vista)

might be possible using autohotkey (which does a lot of the nitty-gritty stuff for you)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the operating system but for Windows you could try using Input Hooks.  I have had to use this before and it works.  The solution is a little complex because you have to write a dll which provides a function address which you can insert in to the input hook chain in Windows.  This is essentially what autohotkey does, but they give a very nice scripting interface and they do all the heavy lifting of setting up the various dlls and Win32 calls on your behalf.  In case you are curious about input hooks: [Hooks Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)